# Chrome control does not work on subsequent pages: "Error: The app's host site url is not set."

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I have a provider-hosted, on-premise app using SharePoint 2013.

The Chrome control works fine when first accessing the app from SharePoint, however, on subsequent pages, the chrome control does not work.

I figured that since my links within the application would not all have the SPHostUrl or SPAppWebURl in the query string parameters, I would store them in a cookie for use on subsequent pages.  This much works, in both cases I get the script url of `http://{hostWeb}/_layouts/15/SP.UI.Controls.js`

However, when I try to apply the chrome control with the code:

```
var sharepointScript = sharepointHostWebUrl + "/_layouts/15/SP.UI.Controls.js";

$.getScript(sharepointScript, function () {
    var options = {
        "appIconUrl": "/Content/images/AppIcon.png",
        "appTitle": appTitle,
        "settingsLinks": [
            {
                "linkUrl": "http://www.google.com",
                "displayName": "Google"
            },
            {
                "linkUrl": "http://www.microsoft.com",
                "displayName" : "Microsoft"
            }
        ]
    };

    var nav = new SP.UI.Controls.Navigation("Chrome", options);
    nav.setVisible(true);
});
```

then the initial page from SharePoint works, but subsequent pages get the JavaScript error:

```
Error: Error: The app's host site url is not set.
Source File: http://{hostweb}/_layouts/15/SP.UI.Controls.js?_=1369967456299
Line: 2
```

I also tried changing to AppWeb instead of hostWeb, but got the same results.

How can I make the Chrome control work on subsequent pages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting the chrome control depends on the query parameters passed to your page, so you need to add these to all internal links something like:

```
"linkUrl": "page2.html?"
        + document.URL.split("?")[1],
```